# Using slim with devise in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, slim-lang

```
rails 5.1.4
Ruby 2.4.2
```

In my Gemfile, I have:

```
gem 'slim'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
```

When I do:

```
rails g devise:views
```

I get:

```
  invoke  Devise::Generators::SharedViewsGenerator
  create    app/views/devise/shared
  create    app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb
  invoke  form_for
  create    app/views/devise/confirmations
  create    app/views/devise/confirmations/new.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/passwords
  create    app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/passwords/new.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/registrations
  create    app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/sessions
  create    app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/unlocks
  create    app/views/devise/unlocks/new.html.erb
  invoke  erb
  create    app/views/devise/mailer
  create    app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/mailer/email_changed.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/mailer/password_change.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb
  create    app/views/devise/mailer/unlock_instructions.html.erb
```

I thought that the slim gem would force the generation of .slim views. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to the [devise repo wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-Haml-and-Slim-Views#create-slim-views) It looks like you have to convert your `erb` views to `slim`.

Answer (score 2):

all you have to do now is convert the views to the slim counterpart

```
for file in app/views/devise/**/*.erb; do erb2slim $file ${file%erb}slim && rm $file; done
```

you can read more about this here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-Haml-and-Slim-Views

> The Haml/Slim view generators were removed from Devise 1.2. Here is a
>   tutorial how to create Haml/Slim views with Devise 1.2 or later.

## Create Slim views

You can use gem called 'html2slim' to create the Slim-views.

`gem install html2slim`

> This package include a tool called erb2slim which can convert erb file to slim recursively. Option -d for delete the erb file after the convert finished.

`erb2slim DIR -d`

I hope that this helps

Happy Hacking